# Angular 4 form hiding select options based on another control's selected value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

In my Angular 4 application I have a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) with multiple [controls](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl).

My those controls are of type [select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), and all of them have the same options:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of form.get('myFormArray')['controls']; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="myControl">
      <option *ngFor="let obj of objects" [ngValue]="obj">{{ obj.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to hide the options that are already selected in some controls of the form array.

**EDIT:**

I solved with a workaround, by setting a `selectedObjects` array in my component (which I keep updated every time a selection change) and using `[hidden]` property on the `<option>`s that I want to exclude.

However I'm wondering if there is a proper solution, possibly using some Angular form's built in, since it appears to be a common problem.

Comment: Where does `objects` come from? If you want each select to have a different list of options, you probably need to have a different `objects` property for each select. You can then update these properties every time the user changes his selection, e.g. `<select (change)="updateOptions()">`.

Comment: `objects` is just an array of objects stored as an attribute of the component's class

Comment: So you can easily update it every time the user changes their selection.

Comment: if I update the `objects` array it doesn't work: as soon as you select something, it disappears not only from the available options but even from the selection.